# using toString on a "child" class where the "parent" is a Hiberneate/JPA class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, tostring

I am working with REST APIs , Java, Hibernate and JPA.

I have a class **Mstrgetnroletype (i.e. role type)** that is part of another class called **ApplicationUser.**

**class ApplicationUser**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPLICATIONUSER", schema = "orcl", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "EMAIL"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "USERNAME") })
public class ApplicationUser implements java.io.Serializable {

    private BigDecimal id;
    private Mstrgenroletype mstrgenroletype;
    private Mstrgenyesno mstrgenyesnoByIsactive;
    private Mstrgenyesno mstrgenyesnoByIsstaff;
    private Mstrgenyesno mstrgenyesnoByIssuperuser;

[.. snip ..]
```

**class Mstrgenroletype**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MSTRGENROLETYPE", schema = "orcl")
public class Mstrgenroletype implements java.io.Serializable {

    private BigDecimal mstrgenroletypeid;
    private String langid;
    private String shortdesc;
    private String longdesc;
    private Set<Applicationuser> applicationusers = new HashSet<Applicationuser>(0);

    public Mstrgenroletype() {
    }

    public Mstrgenroletype(BigDecimal mstrgenroletypeid) {
        this.mstrgenroletypeid = mstrgenroletypeid;
    }

    public Mstrgenroletype(BigDecimal mstrgenroletypeid, String langid, String shortdesc, String longdesc,
            Set<Applicationuser> applicationusers) {
        this.mstrgenroletypeid = mstrgenroletypeid;
        this.langid = langid;
        this.shortdesc = shortdesc;
        this.longdesc = longdesc;
        this.applicationusers = applicationusers;
    }

    @Id

    @Column(name = "MSTRGENROLETYPEID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getMstrgenroletypeid() {
        return this.mstrgenroletypeid;
    }

    public void setMstrgenroletypeid(BigDecimal mstrgenroletypeid) {
        this.mstrgenroletypeid = mstrgenroletypeid;
    }

    @Column(name = "LANGID", length = 2)
    public String getLangid() {
        return this.langid;
    }

    public void setLangid(String langid) {
        this.langid = langid;
    }

    @Column(name = "SHORTDESC", length = 10)
    public String getShortdesc() {
        return this.shortdesc;
    }

    public void setShortdesc(String shortdesc) {
        this.shortdesc = shortdesc;
    }

    @Column(name = "LONGDESC", length = 20)
    public String getLongdesc() {
        return this.longdesc;
    }

    public void setLongdesc(String longdesc) {
        this.longdesc = longdesc;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mstrgenroletype")
    public Set<Applicationuser> getApplicationusers() {
        return this.applicationusers;
    }

    public void setApplicationusers(Set<Applicationuser> applicationusers) {
        this.applicationusers = applicationusers;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Mstrgenroletype [mstrgenroletypeid=" + mstrgenroletypeid + ", langid=" + langid + ", shortdesc="
                + shortdesc + ", longdesc=" + longdesc + "]";
    }

}
```

I am trying to make a method of **"toString"** that will print out the contents of the variable associated with **ApplicationUser**.

The problem is that when printing out the contents of the variable associated with **Mstrgenroletype**, I get an error of

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   - no Session

This is because it is trying to print the contents associated with the class of **Mstrgenroletype.** (I know this because when I remove the print statement assocaited with variable that is linked to the class, everything works)

BEFORE (getting the error)

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ApplicationUser [id=" + id +  ", password=" + password + ", username=" + ", role=" + mstrgenroletype.toString() 
        + username + ", firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", email=" + email + ", userid="
        + userid + ", apptenantid=" + apptenantid + ", appkeyid=" + appkeyid + ", profilepic=" + profilepic +  "]";     

    }
```

AFTER (Mstrgenroltype variable removed, getting no error)

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ApplicationUser [id=" + id +  ", password=" + password + ", username=" 
        + userid + ", apptenantid=" + apptenantid + ", appkeyid=" + appkeyid + ", profilepic=" + profilepic +  "]";     

    }
```

I have made sure that the class with **Mstrgenroletype** **does have a toString** method as well.

How can I print the variable associated with *Mstrgenroletype*?

Comment: So why are you using fields directly in toString when that will load them (if not loaded)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoke the `toString()` method on a `ApplicationUser` object that didn't load the `mstrgenroletype` relationship eagerly.
As `ApplicationUser.toString()` method invokes the `toString()` method of the object referenced by `mstrgenroletype`, it throws an exception because the `ApplicationUser` object is currently a Hibernate proxy that can load relationship only in the frame of a Hibernate session.
But according to the thrown exception, you don't have any currently opened session during the `toString()` invocation.

> How can I print the variable associated with Mstrgenroletype?

First, you should avoid having a `toString()` which the results depends on a persistence session.
It mix things. `toString()` is for debugging an object, not for fetching fields with query executions.
It is an important side effect you **have to** avoid.
So I advise to write a `toString()` method that relies only on own fields of the entity as this one you wrote in your workaround.
This rule should also be followed for `equals()` or `hashCode()` methods

Of course if functionally you need to retrieve the relationship, add it in your query with a fetch join.
If it is not the case and you want only to debug the object relationships you can add a breakpoint in your IDE in a class where the Hibernate session is opened and the object retrieved and dig into the relationship with IDE tools (display or execute feature in Eclipse).

Comment: hi and thanks for the response. In it, you said:"Of course if functionally you need to retrieve the relationship, add it in your query with a fetch join."  I am new to Hibernate - is there a sample link on this? TIA

Comment: Hey :) You are welcome. Sure. The Hibernate documentation is not bad.  The fetching takes multiple forms. Here is a point about fetchind and query : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching